# Eight backslashes required to replace single backslash with double backslashes?

Tags: java, regex, string

This is a "what the heck is going on here" question.  I don't actually need a solution.

I had to replace all single backslashes in a String with double backslashes .  This is what I ended up doing...

```
strRootDirectory = strRootDirectory.replaceAll("\\\\", "\\\\\\\\");
```

...where strRootDirectory is a java.lang.String above.

Now, I understand the four backslashes for the first argument: regex expects two backslashes in order to indicate a single literal backslash, and java wants them doubled up.  That's fine.

BUT, what the heck is going on with the eight backslashes for the second argument?  Isn't the replacement string supposed to be a literal (non-regex, I mean) string?  I expected to need four backslashes in the second argument, in order to represent two backslashes.

Comment: Yeah, Java backslash hell. Try Python: `re.sub(r"\\", r"\\\\", mystr)`

Comment: Or simply use the appropriate tool for the job - don't use regex when you don't need it...

Comment: Or use the appropriate operating system for the job - don't use Windows when you don't need it.  Note that Java supports forward slashes where Windows would normally want backslashes.

Comment: Maybe I'll switch to pen, paper and abacus.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The second argument isn't a regex-string, but a regex-replacement-string, in which the backslash also has a special meaning (it is used to escape the special character `$` used for variable interpolation and is also used to escape itself).

From The API:

> Note that backslashes (`\`) and dollar signs (`$`) in the replacement string may cause the results to be different than if it were being treated as a literal replacement string; see `Matcher.replaceAll`. Use `Matcher.quoteReplacement(java.lang.String)` to suppress the special meaning of these characters, if desired.
>
> -- [http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(...)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Comment: OIC!  I thought argument two was a verbatim string (i.e. no special characters involved) to be written in place of argument one's regex string.  Thanks!

Comment: No problem John. The same thing baffled me when I first encountered it! :)

Comment: @JohnFitzpatrick the `String.replace()` function takes 2 verbatim strings (no regex or special chars involved) see my answer

Comment: @ratchet freak, yeah, `replace(...)` is the better option here.

Comment: @ratchet: Thanks for affirming my sanity.  I was sure that in some form of String replacement the second argument was a literal.

Answer (score 6):

It's easier if you use `replace("\\","\\\\")` ([`String.replace`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) takes literal strings and is more efficient when it's all literal)

or you can ensure correctness through the `Pattern.quote` and `Matcher.quoteReplacement` functions

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. With replace() I'd have to loop until done because the original string has many backslashes, and then on the second iteration I suspect the first backslash found will be the one that I just put there from the last replace(). Infinite loop I think, unless replace() can track what it last replaced.

Comment: no it "Replaces *each* substring of this string that matches the literal target sequence with the specified literal replacement sequence." check the link in the answer

Answer (score 2):

`"\\\\\\\\"` leads to an in memory representation of a string with 4 backslashes: `\\\\`. Although the second string isn't a regex string, backslashes and dollar signs are still special characters in it, so they need to be escaped.

Comment: But the replacement isn't a regex string: other regex meta characters need not be escaped.

Comment: It isn't an ordinary string either. See the link `Bart` posted.

Comment: I know, it's the same Bart. :)

Comment: @BartKiers: Ah, sorry. I didn't look at your name when reading your comment, I thought the OP had written it :-)

Answer (score 1):

According to Java reference material, the replaceAll method interprets backslashes in the replacement string as escape characters too.  They could be used to escape the dollar sign character, which could refer to matched expressions to re-use in the replacement string.  so naturally, if you want to double the number of backslashes, and both parameters treat backslash as an escape character, you need twice as many backslashes in the replacement string.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, it gets hairy when you need to do this sort of thing, doesn't it.

The reason you need so many backslashes is that you need to take into account that backslash is used for both escaping a string and for escaping a regex.

- Take 1 backslash.
- Double it for string escaping.
- Double it again for regex escaping.
- Double it again because you need to match two consecutive backslashes in your original string.

That makes 8.

Answer (score 1):

As a fan of not getting into super detailed explanations of regex... I figured out from the major answer post by Bart Kiers above:

```
System.out.println( "line1: "+"hello\\\\world" );
System.out.println( "line2: "+"hello\\\\world".replaceAll("\\\\\\\\", Matcher.quoteReplacement("\\") ) );
```

prints out

```
line1: hello\\world
line2: hello\world
```

I hope it helps...