# replaceFirst ArrayOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, regex, replace

I'm getting a strange `ArrayOutOfBoundsException` when using `replaceFirst`:

```
"this is an example string".replaceFirst("(^this )", "$1\\") // throws ArrayOutOfBoundsException
"this is an example string".replaceFirst("(^this )", "$1") // works fine
```

I'm trying to achieve this string:

```
"this \is an example string"
```

Why am I getting an ArrayOutOfBoundsException if I try to put in escaped backslashes in the replacement String? This is happening on Android, if it makes a difference

Here is an [ideone](http://ideone.com/l4SIRC) example of the exception.

Here is the logcat exception stack trace:

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: index=14
>           at java.util.regex.Matcher.appendEvaluated(Matcher.java:149)
>           at java.util.regex.Matcher.appendReplacement(Matcher.java:111)
>           at java.util.regex.Matcher.replaceFirst(Matcher.java:304)
>           at java.lang.String.replaceFirst(String.java:1793)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use this regex:-

```
"this is an example string".replaceFirst("(^this )", "$1\\\\");
```

because the `\` needs to be double escaped. Therefore, for every `\` you'll need 4`\` (Initially you'd 2 `\`, so providing this info, in case you need to change it later).

Quoting a few lines from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7766787/2024761):-

> The second argument isn't a regex-string, but a
>   regex-replacement-string, in which the backslash also has a special
>   meaning (it is used to escape the special character $ used for
>   variable interpolation and is also used to escape itself)

Comment: All: Surely the replacement isn't regex, so why would it need to be double-escaped?

Comment: @RGraham - Check the answer link I've provided. It explains the reason for double-escaping the backslash.

Answer (score 2):

```
"this is an example string".replaceFirst("(^this )", "$1\\")
```

In the code above, `\\` is really just a single `\` (first backslash is used to escape the second one, since backslash in Strings is for escaping other things, and does not mean anything by itself).

But! In regular expression single backslash is used for escaping purposes itself, so it needs to be escaped once more. Hence, if you need a literal backslash in a regular expression String in Java, you need to write four backslashes `"\\\\"`.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
"this is an example string".replaceFirst("(^this )", "$1\\\\");
```

Output:

```
this \is an example string
```

the `replaceFirst` like `replaceAll` function on String  executes a regular expression and you have to first escape the `\`because it's a literal (yielding `\\`), and then escape it again because of the regular expression (yielding `\\\\`).

Comment: Sorry, I updated my question. I only need one backslash in the resulting string

Answer (score 1):

You will need:

```
"this is an example string".replaceFirst("(^this )", "$1\\\\");
```

because of double escaping needed in regex.

**PS:** Even though replaced string is not really a regex but due to use use if grouped variables like `$1`, `$2` etc it is still processed by regex engine and therefore need of double escaping.

**In contrast if you want to avoid regex then simply use `Sring#replace(String n, String r)`:

```
"this is an example string".replace("this ", "this \\")
```

**Clearly here there is no regex involved hence only single escaping is enough.**